# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be emptyy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= submit %>
 <% end %>
```

................plz help me out of this problem....................

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
end
```

when i execute this code its show this error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Comment: Don't think the duplicate attached to this is relevant - the answer doesn't help solve this. @ahsanamir, the above looks OK, assuming your form is rendered in `posts/new.html.erb`. Have you tried inspecting the contents of `@post` as the form is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in db/create_post.rb

```
t.string :title
t.text :body
```

then do rake db:migrate (it migrate schema of data base)

```
 class PostController < ApplicationController


   before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
       @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
       @post = Post.new(post_params)
       if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path
       else
        render 'new'
       end
     end

     def show

     end

    def post_params
       params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    end
```

in post/new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @post do |f|%>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br>
<%= f.label :body %><br>
<%= f.text_area :body %><br>
<%end%>
```

in post/index.html.erb

```
<%@post.each do |post|%>
<%=post.title%>
<%=post.body%>
<%end%>
```